# clicking one hyperlink to change the css styles of more than one different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-slides

I am having different div's on my website and I would like  to do following

- when I am clicking one link, that will trigger a change inside the css code of more than one div's. For example if I click on clients I would like to make the ul element with class="rslides" to get property of heigh="0px" and than another div layer to expand below this one.

**But I have 2 problems:**

1. first is that I am using a responsive slider for which i to make its height="0px" , I have to change the  class property.
2. other issue is how to make one link trigger 2 actions for the second div. I tried with triggers but it is limited to one element per "id"

**DOM Structure:**

```
    <div id="slider">
       <div id="index_slider">
         <ul class="rslides" >
             <li><img src="img/index_design_02.jpg"></li>
                 <li><img src="img/index_design_03.jpg"></li>                 
         </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
<script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
    speed: 1000,
    maxwidth: 1200
      });
  });
</script>



<div id="menu"><a href="#rslides">clients</a></div>
<div id="second_slider"></div>
```

**THE CSS CODE fot the both tirgers of the slider:**

```
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;  
  -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;

}

.rslides:target {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; 
  height:0px;


}
```

Here is link to [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vladicorp/4tRVZ/)

where my goal is once clicked on the link the div called "menu" to go on the top with sliding transition and the other div called "second_slider" to expand on the bottom, and the slider to disapear.

Comment: to add a class to to any element, what you could do is use this `.addClass(<ClassName>)` . were `<ClassName>` is a css class which would set the `height:0`.

Comment: the second requirement i didnt get it *other issue is how to make one link trigger 2 actions or the second div.* what you meant by this ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your markup, you should be able to target more than one div. The only limitation would be each target must a child of your link target.

```
<div class="rslides">
  <div id="target-a">
    <div class="sub-target-one"></div>
    <div class="sub-target-two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The way you would go about it is like this:

```
.rslides:target > .sub-target-one,
.rsiides:target > .sub-target-two {
  /* rules go here */
}
```

Comment: This will work on hover, how it will be on link click ? and here target-one and target-two will have the same properities, how we can do it for them to have different css styles ?

Comment: I'm not following, my understanding is the `:target` pseudo-class will work when you assign a target to a link, e.g., http://mylink.net#target. You may use `:active` for clicks but these are limited to when you are actually pushing the button.